# Detecting the dependency of a probability distribution

Tags: distributions, independence, deep-belief-networks

I have this joint probability distribution between the two binary values $A$ and $B$
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A& B& P(A,B)\\ \hline
 0& 0 &.40\\ 
 0& 1 &.30\\ 
 1& 0 &.20\\ 
 1& 1 &.10\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

It's clear that $P(A,B) \neq P(A)P(B)$ but if I wanted to draw a Bayesian belief network, how can I derive which variable is dependent on the other?

i.e. which of these two would be the correct belief network
[image]

Comment: Unless you have marginal distributions and/or make some assumptions such as discarding *negative* influence, I don't believe this is identifiable.

Comment: @jkm Since the full joint distribution is known, the marginals are (easily) deducible.  Exactly which marginal distributions are you referring to, then?

Comment: Sorry, had a brain-fart. I meant the priors.